# How to load a node given a menu link id?

Tags: 8, entities

I have this id via `$link->getParent()`:

```
menu_link_content:6cf83fce-228f-42da-bc39-bea06c767510
```

How do I get the node id of that menu link?

Answer (score 5):

Something like:

```
if ('entity.node.canonical' == $link->getRouteName()) {
  $params = $link->getRouteParameters();
  $nid = $params['node'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [EntityRepository::loadEntityByUuid()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!EntityRepository.php/function/EntityRepository::loadEntityByUuid/8.4.x) for a non-deprecated way of loading by UUID.

Comment: that would load the menu item, not the node?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the node from the (already depreciated) entityManager using the UUID:

```
$node = \Drupal::entityManager()->loadEntityByUuid('6cf83fce-228f-42da-bc39-bea06c767510');
```

Comment: why would I want to use a deprecated method? :) whats the not deprecated way? thanks!

Comment: it says `Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: "The "1365f9ba-2052-4773-827a-2475f1347aa0" entity type does not exist."`

Comment: I would use the depreciated method mostly because the documentation and tutorials haven't yet been updated to make it clear how to use the replacement interface based solution. And because D8 will have a long shelf life so I would not be too worried about using a D8-only solution.  If you need more help more code/context would be useful.

Comment: the menu:uuid string actually loads the menu link, not the corresponding node

Comment: see my above comment please

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on simesy's answer.

```
$menu_id = $link->getParent();
$menu_link_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link');
$menu_item = $menu_link_manager->createInstance($menu_id);
if ('entity.node.canonical' == $menu_item->getRouteName()) {
  $params = $menu_item->getRouteParameters();
  $nid = $params['node'];
}
```

Comment: How to get a node by menu link as `$entity->id()` with bundle `'menu_link_content'` inside of the function `mymodulename_entity_update()` ? If I use your way, I receive the error `Call to undefined method Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent::getRouteParameters()...`